# \makebox inside 3rd argument of \setfoot generates error

Tags: boxes, titlesec

If I replace the current version `\setfoot` with that commented out, I get: "Missing \begin{document}". I guess it has to do with the fact it is flushed right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{rest}
{%
  \sethead{}{}{}
%  \setfoot{Tenant Initials:\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}}{}{Landlord Initials:\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}} % Missing \begin{document}
  \setfoot{Tenant Initials:\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}}{}{}
}
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagestyle{rest}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use more primitive construct instead `\makebox[3em]{\hrulefil}`, i.e. `\vrule height.4pt width3em\relax` or `\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}` then you have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious problem.

Workaround: brace the offending part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{rest}
{%
  \sethead{}{}{}%
  \setfoot
    {Tenant Initials:\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}}% left
    {}% center
    {Landlord Initials:{\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}}}% right
}
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\pagestyle{rest}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It has to do with the complicated way `titleps` absorbs the arguments to `\setfoot` and `\sethead`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in macro `\ttl@duplthreeargs` which does  `#1#2#3#4->#1[#2][#3][#4]{#2}{#3}{#4}` but should do `#1#2#3#4->#1[{#2}][{#3}][{#4}]{#2}{#3}{#4}` or at least for `#4`, as the `][` delimiters are less likely to arise from `#2` and `#3` than is a lone `]` for `#4`.  Else any `]` in `#4` as here from the `\makebox[3em]{\hrulefill}` breaks the correct flow of things at next macro `\ttl@setfoot` which fetches delimited `[#1][#2][#3]#4#5#6` arguments. Here the `#3` ends up being faulty `Landlord Initials:\makebox [3em`.

Workaround given in [egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685057/293669), and the above was alluded to in @egreg comment attached to his answer.